# How to get the domain of the parent window of a popup?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am writing a plugin for wordpress, and I provide a way for users to log in to my service, when they click on *log in* a popup opens with the service's website (which is on a different url than the wordpress blog).

So to avoid cross domain errors, I use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) This works great but the second argument of postmessage is the domain name of the website to send the data to.

I did a lot of research and all the examples seem to hardcode the domain name directly into it, but since it's a wordpress plugin, any domain can go there.

So I want to get the domain name of the parent window (the one who opened the popup).

I noticed that [firefox manages to extract the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcYFL.png)
 when using the developer tools but I can't seem to manage to do it myself as almost all the properties are restricted.

So how can I get the url/domain name of the parent window for my popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy forbids JavaScript access to the location of a page on a different origin.

However, from the documentation you link to:

> targetOrigin
>   Specifies what the origin of targetWindow must be for the event to be dispatched, either as **the literal string "*" (indicating no preference)** or as a URI.

If you want to limit message reading to a selection of origins (without making it public), then you could try to post a message to each in turn, or you could have the parent send its origin to the child (either through `postMessage` — although that has issues with timing, since you have to wait for the new page to load — or by simply passing it in the query string when requesting the page.

Answer (score -1):

Pass it to your login page via query string added to the end of your service's website that opens your pop up.

Example:

```
var myservice = 'myservice.com?'+window.location.href;
```

Then from your site you get the parts you need and create a variable and substitute that for the hard coded address.

Getting the parts:

```
var prot = window.location.protocol;
var dom = window.location.host;
var path = window.location.pathname;
var qry = window.location.search;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  dom + path + qry;
```

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. Other than the fact that I didn't know how to use the gray highlight in my original answer and Lee Taylor corrected that, I believe I answered the question which was "So I want to get the domain name of the parent window (the one who opened the popup)."

Comment: I guess the answer got downvoted because the OP is writing a plugin so he cannot simply change the code of the original wordpress websites, so your answer is not applicaple to the problem at hand.